# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable python

Tags: python, pandas, http-error

I used to access csv file from the following links for years.

http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1819/E0.csv

It was,first of all, open source. I used to read it and convert it to data frame using Pandas

Today, when I tried to access it, it shown the follow error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable python
```

But when I just directly open from the browser, I can open the same link and see the data inside.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks A lot.

Zep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It is due to network. In my office Anaconda/Jupiter notebook can't connect to internet however I am able to open the link in browser. Not sure whats your condition. If you are in office network. Try making your mobile as hotspot, come out of office network and then try.

Comment: It was usually ok when running at Office.

Comment: May be I will try at home.

Comment: I am not able to open link using browser at my office. I can open the link  using 4G on my phone